# How to create an "OR" Symfony Validator Constraint

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony4

How would one go about creating a Symfony 4.2 constraint that validates multiple batches of constraints, but fails **only** if **all** of them fail?

Here's my use case.

I want to validate a variable that can be either an object of specific class, or an array representing an object of the same class. I would then have 2 cases:

1. I would want to validate against `Type(type=array)` constraint and then a `Collection(fields={...})` constraint to ensure this is an array with proper structure that I can then deserialize and get the object;
2. or I would want to validate against `Type(type=MyClassName)`.

So, the final constraint should succeed if either case 1 or case 2 succeeds, and should fail only if both fail (say a `string` is passed).

I feel groups could be useful somehow, but I am not entirely sure how exactly to use them in this case.

---

I already have an idea how to implement this, but somehow it fails and I can't figure out why:

```php
$violations1 = $this->context->getValidator()->validate($value, $constraints1);
$violations2 = $this->context->getValidator()->validate($value, $constraints2);

// Check both violations and if at least one of them is empty - succeed.
// If all of them fail, copy violations to the current context.
```

As you can see I would validate the value against `$constraints1` which is an array of constraints to check if the value is a valid array. Then I would validate the value against `$constraints2` which is a different array of constraints that checks if the value is an object of specific class.

At this point I want to just copy the violations and fail, or succeed if either `$violations1` or `$violations2` are empty.

The problem is, that for some reason `$violations2` is **always** empty, even if it should fail. As if the validator refuses to validate the same value twice, even if it's against a different set of constraints. Is this true and how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [expression constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html). It allows to combine multiple tests with 'or'.

Comment: No, that's not how `Choice` works. It validates that the given value is identical to one of the supplied choices. What I need is to have the value validated successfully against one of the supplied arrays of **constraints**, not values.

Comment: Damn, you are right. I thought the choice constraint would be able to work with an array of additional constraints. Apparently it can't. That would leave custom callback constraint or the expression constraint as two valid options.

Comment: Yes, but both have the same issue I am facing in the edit to the question. I need to validate the data twice against two different sets of constraints and then "tell" that validation failed because *XYZ*..